# vue Route Manipulation. (#)

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router

For Page filtering purposes we save properties in the url query.

```
this.$router.push({ query: newQuery })
```

Works fine.
The result is

```
://foo.com/bar/page/?queryPropOne=xyz&queryPropTwo=zyx
```

But we came across a SEO Problem and we need to set a **#** in front of the query parameters.
How can I achieve this with Vue-Router? (Using **NuxtJS**)

The result should be like:

```
://foo.com/bar/page#/?queryPropOne=xyz&queryPropTwo=zyx
```

Comment: What kind of SEO problem do you have that this can be solved with a `#`?

Comment: Text behind a # in a url query is ignored by e.g. Google, without it SE's would think there are many sub-pages. It is more an optimisation than a problem.

Comment: Not sure how to solve your problem, but this module may maybe help: https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module